# Chrome extension to replace Twitter words

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to make a code extension that will replace one word with another on Twitter. There's [code shared on GitHub](https://github.com/GeneticJen/Twitter-word-replace/blob/master/replaceWord.js)from 2016 that says it should work, but is having no effect when I apply the extension in my browser. Can anyone help with the issue here? Has Twitter changed too much since this code was written for it to currently work, or is there another issue? When I upload the unpacked extension into Chrome it isn't detecting any errors, but I'm not getting any results.

```
(function() {
  function replaceTwitterWord() {
    var tweetContent = document.querySelectorAll(".tweet-text");

    [].slice.call(tweetContent).forEach(function(el){
      var newContent = el.innerHTML.replace(/OLD_WORD_NO_QUOTATION_MARKS/g,"NEW_WORD_IN_QUOTATION MARKS");
      if (newContent != el.innerHTML) {
        el.innerHTML = newContent;
      }
    });
  }

  function tick() {
    replaceTwitterWord();
    window.setTimeout(tick, 5000);
  }

  tick();
})();
```

Comment: have you looked for the `.tweet-text` class / element in the source code for the Twitter site?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like Twitter has changed plenty of things since then. At least there is no more elements having class '.tweet-text' so you have to get another tool.